# Irreducible components of the subvariety of matrices s.t. $M^n=\mathbb{I}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, describe the irreducible components, and prove that there are ${n+1\choose{2}}$ of them, of the following algebraic variety:
$$V=\{A\in M_{2}(\mathbb{C})\mid A^n=\mathbb{I}\}$$

For $n=2$, the components are $\{\mathbb{I}\}$, $\{-\mathbb{I}\}$ and

$$ \left\{  \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}: \ \ a=-d \ , \ \  a^2+bc=1 \ \right\}$$
For the other values of $n$, I don't have idea how to proceed

Comment: So you have for $n=2$ three components: these are distinguished by their eigenvalues, respectively $(1,1)$, $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,-1)$, and therefore also by their characteristic equations.

Comment: Ok, so the minimal polinomial of A must divide $x^n-1$. Let $a_{1}$...$a_{n}$ be the roots of the unity. Then, if the minimal polinomial is linear, we obtain $A=a_i\mathbb{I}$, and thus $P_A(x)=(x-a_i)^2$ . Otherwise, in order to buld a possible characteristical polynomial we have to chose two differents roots, no matter the order. In total, we obtain $\(n+1\chose2\)$ different polynomials. Each of one determines an irreducible component. If I am right I will edit the answer